# データベースの暗号化

Tags: database

SQL Server か Oracle、PostgresあたりのメジャーどころのRDBのどれかを使うというところまでは決まっているのですが・・・

いくつか暗号化の方法はあると思うのですが

- 暗号化したい列だけを暗号化した場合
  データベースの暗号化した列の内容を検索する際、全文検索をする方法はそれぞれあるようなのですが(DB毎に方法が異なるのは面倒ですが)
  SelectするSQL文そのものを暗号化する方法というのはあるのでしょうか
  パスワードをSQL文に入れたりすると電文で何を検索してるかわかってしまうでしょうし(デバッグは楽かもしれませんが)
  何かしら方法はあるとは思うのですが
- 個別の列の暗号化が面倒でデータベースそのものを暗号化する手法を取った場合
  　暗号化のキーの管理はどうしているのでしょう

Comment: 何のために暗号化したいのかという部分が書かれていなくて、どうして SQL を暗号化なさりたいのかがよく分かりませんでした。本文を [edit] して追記いただけませんでしょうか？（本当に暗号化が必要あるんでしょうか、という所から考えています）

Comment: 文面からして単純な興味ではなく、具体的なアプリケーションを考えているのだと思いますが、どのような構成なのか（単一マシン内にRDBMSとクライアントソフトが相乗りしているのか、間にアプリケーションサーバなどを介してインターネットに公開するのか）や、想定している攻撃について書いてみてはどうでしょうか。（私も暗号化が必要かどうか疑問ですし、SQL文を暗号化しなければならない状況というのがちょっと思いつきません）

Comment: パスワードならハッシュ化すべきで、ハッシュ化されたデータを電文やデータベースファイル上で暗号化したいのか？というのは気になります。